# java / Servlets / ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8, character-encoding, response

I have **set character encoding of the response to UTF-8** by

`response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`

Despite that, on the client-side, several characters are broken. I had a look at the response's header in the browser tool, and i found out that the **encoding was set to ISO-8859-1**.

How can i solve this issue? What is the underlying problem?

Answer (score 5):

I have found the problem:

`response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` must be declared **before** `response.getWriter();`